# Can a MOV properly discharge a X-Capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, safety, mov

I created an AC-DC SMPS with a EMI filter that consists of a X-Capacitor and Common-Mode Choke. IEC 62368-1 requires that capacitors be discharged below ES1 (60V) within 2s of being disconnected. As can be seen in the picture below, I placed 2x 1.5MΩ across the line to ensure that the X2 Capacitor will discharge if the power is disconnected when the full peak voltage is present on the capacitor (424V in this case).

As you may notice, a MOV is also across the line. Since these always leak some current, how can I ensure it will discharge CX1 in the time required? Are the resistors still required to ensure proper discharge when the MOV fails or ages?

[image: X Capacitor Discharging Circuit]

Comment: The MOV is in parallel with the resistors hence if it works with the resistors then it will work when the MOV is there. Have you got a fuse fitted for when the capacitor fails?

Comment: *Since these always leak some current...* Sure, but I do not see **how much** that would be in the datasheet. There is no reliable information regarding how the MOV behaves with voltages below rated voltage (at least, I could not find it) so there are also **no guarantees** that the MOV will discharge the capacitor properly. In my opinion, since there is no guarantee, you still need to have the resistors present as well.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie 's answer makes sense. I mostly wanted to know if it was common industry practice as these Resistors are not always there. Some companies even sell  ICs to take care of the discharging without imposing power losses during operation.

Comment: Bimpelrekkie is right, there is no guarantee that the MOV has a significant leakage, and it is not designed for that; it should be instead insulated for all normal operating voltages. When the MOV fails for e.g. ageing, well, it happens, once, but you shall discharge the capacitor to a safe voltage *always*. To prevent the short circuit caused by the failed MOV (for a matter of availability) they are usually fused on distribution lines.
@CharlesGervais Curiosity: examples of those ICs that take care of the discharging when the power cord gets disconnected?